# Doctrine and FOSUserBundle - displaying users according to their roles

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I need to be able to display all ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN users in a paginated table. I have the table displaying *everyone* correctly using Doctrine's `findBy()` method, but I'm a bit stumped on how to filter by role.  Roles are saved as a `DC2Type:array`, and the role data itself looks a bit like JSON:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:9:"ROLE_USER";}
```

With that, I'm curious as to what to pass into `findBy()` to select all ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN users.

In other words:

```
$users = $em->getRepository('Acme\SiteBundle\Entity\User')->findBy(array(/* what do I put here? */), array('id' => 'asc'), $perPage, $perPage * ($page - 1));
```

---

EDIT: Hmm... it looks like `findBy()` may not be the way to go here after all.  D'oh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notation is the serialization of a PHP array - this means that `FOSUserBundle` does not normalize the user-roles relationship.

But you can provide you own user class and overload the roles getters/setters, or if you don't have to deal with that many users, you can overload the user repository by fetching all users and filtering by role.

A dirty hack would be to issue a `LIKE` search on the roles field, as the role name is still readable, but it would be kind of bad performance wise.

You can find more info in [this repository issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/258).

Comment: Yeah, using `LIKE` was the 'best' way for me to go given the system I inherited.  Unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I think coupling each role in a [group](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/groups.md) and working with groups would be much more better. Specially assign and decline <strike>roles</strike> groups gets easier as it's a simple relation. Also query for a specfic group gets easy.